# SQL Express Silent install, not correctly setting sa password

Tags: sql-server, powershell, passwords

sorry if this isn't the right SO page to ask this.

I'm working on a script to silently install SQL Express 2019. It works, except once the SQL server instance installs and I try to log into it with the sa account, I get an invalid password error. I don't know what's happening from when I provide the password to how it processes it.

Below is how I'm providing the password

```
$pass = read-host "enter SQL sa password" -AsSecureString

# install sql -location already with source
.\setup.exe /SAPWD=$pass /ConfigurationFile=ConfigurationFile.ini
```

The install works, no issues, just when I try to use the SA account, what I set as the password isn't what gets set(I have no idea what does). I can login with windows auth and change the password to what I want, but that is counter-productive to what i'm trying to do.

does anyone have any ideas what is happening to the password that I provide? I'm trying to have it prompt for input, rather than hardcode it into the config file.

Comment: The problem is that you think that `$pass` has the value you typed. Open a Powershell window and enter `$pass = read-host "enter SQL sa password" -AsSecureString` and enter a password. Then type `$pass` and hit [Return]; you don't get the password you entered you get `System.Security.SecureString`. You've set the password for the `sa` account to be `System.Security.SecureString`.

Comment: thank you! you were right lol, I had the secure string get unencrypted to be used for that purpose, but I just wasn't using that variable there. 
Stare at a script long enough and you miss the little things